# Distributes tracing of order flows

Tags: java, microservices, grpc, spring-cloud-sleuth, zipkin

We are running a java trading application and have around 50 orders per second. When an order comes in, it jumps between services and we want to measure latency inside every service and between services by an external service which should gather all data with timestamps and produce distributions with percentiles. We want to measure latency for every order in order to find issues and explain them to our members if they have latency-related questions. The issue we are facing is a framework to choose to propagate orders from every service to another service with timestamps attached to calculate and produce latencies. Given the flow of orders we have, what will be the most promising approach for us?  We looked into Zipkin, it also supports gRPC - does it fit our use-case? Any other recommendations?

p.s. we cannot use the transport we use for the business logic as we are going to get rid of it soon.

Comment: This question is too broad and open-ended for this site.  This site is for asking specific programming-related questions, not for asking these sorts of "what general approach should I take?" questions.  Even if this were the appropriate venue, I doubt very much that anyone could give you a decent answer with what little info you've provided.  It would likely depend on various aspects of your microservice architecture, like how you're communicating between services, what orchestration you're using, what frameworks you're basing your code on, etc.

Comment: Thanks maybe people can share some experience as we are looking for different options to take the right decision. I dont know any other venue to ask this questio  where I can find competent people as on this website.

Comment: Have you checked out other sites in the StackExchange ecosystem?

Comment: Well, you definitely can achieve your goals with Zipkin. Also it is not necessary to measure every order, try to find proper `sampleRate`.